# ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 32)

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning

I am trying to generate prediction matrix for a single image with my trained model but got this error. I wonder if anyone could help me out?

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import Sequential
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('1340.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = img.astype('float32')
img /= 255
model = load_model('mymodel.h5')
predictions=model.predict(img)
print('predicted model:', predictions)
```

Comment: Reshape the image to `(1, 32, 32, 3)` (this requires splitting R, G, and B values into different dimensions)

Comment: @Maxim  `img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` = color conversion to grayscale (so its only 1 grayscalevalue instead of RGB)?

Comment: OK. Then it would be easier. Reshape to `(1, 32, 32, 1)`. But the model should also start with 1-channel input